# Solar Powered Sump Pump

Tags: basement, flooding

Our basement floods when the power goes out. The obvious solution is to make a backup. My fathers plan is to use a solar panel to power a battery, from there he can unplug the sump from the house to a converter. I’ve seen people make automated systems but he’s trying to spend as little as possible on the project. Others used a separate sump and float switch directly above their already existing sump pump. My father is always home he doesn’t have a need for the automation. Upon building a mock-up he directly plugs alligator clips from the battery to the converter. I recommended (with my knowledge from circuits 1) that he uses a controller to separate the components as when he tried this the dewalt converter seemingly instantly fried from the 12v battery. I can provide pictures and numbers for anyone willing to help.

Comment: In general, you just can't connect two power sources in parallel unless 1) they are designed by the manufacturer for that configuration  or 2) you provide the properly designed ORing circuit external to the two power supplies.

Comment: How long is the power off for? How about a Jackery or Goal Zero battery with solar charging(and ac)?

Comment: How big is the sump pump (Watts)?   After a big storm, how much does it run and for how long (eg 50% cycle for a few days).   How big a solar installation (W) and what size batteries (Wh) are you planning?  Are your storms in winter when cloudy weather may follow for days?

Comment: Solar power production tends to be awful when sump pumps are needed most. If there's municipal water a water-powered backup sump pump might be a better plan. Else a properly set up generator with the sump pump on the generator supplied circuits. Or your solar system will need some LARGE batteries to carry enough power from when it's sunny.

Answer (score 2):

There are several options that might work.  If you're dead set on using solar for your battery recharging and maintaining, look for a secondary sump pump that runs off of 12V, and just hook that 12V sump pump float switch to a battery that's continually trickle charged from your solar power source of suitable voltage.

Since I live in a house with a well, I have a similar setup to what I have mentioned above with a separate 12V sump system in the same pit as my primary sump pump.  This separate system uses a 12V deep cycle marine battery and a control system designed for this application.

But there are other options if you consider non-solar systems.  If you're on a commercial water supply, there are also backup sump pumps that run off of commercial water pressure.  They do use a fair amount of water to pump water out, but it negates the need for a separate power system for the backup system.

In any case, I'd recommend setting up a separate backup system, so if your primary system fails, your backup still can function to keep your basement dry.